# Problem with converting time according to timezone in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

I am trying to convert a DateTime into UTC from a source timezone. Date, time and timezone are taken as inputs from a user (presented as dropdown menu options).

Following is a portion of the code utilized for conversion:

```
string inputDateString = "2019-11-12T09:00:00.000"; //Taken as input from user
string inputTimeZoneString = "(UTC-03:00) Brasilia"; // Taken as input from user

DateTime dtStartdatetime = DateTime.Parse(inputDateString);

string sourceTimeZone = string.Empty;
foreach (TimeZoneInfo a in TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones())
{
     if (a.DisplayName == objCalendar.timezone)
     {
          sourceTimeZone = a.Id;
     }
     string strTimeZone = a.DisplayName.Substring(a.DisplayName.IndexOf(')') + 1);
     string strTimeZone1 = objCalendar.timezone.Substring(objCalendar.timezone.IndexOf(')') + 1);
     if (strTimeZone.Trim() == strTimeZone1.Trim())
     {
          sourceTimeZone = a.Id;
     }
}

DateTime utc_time_start = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dtStartdatetime, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(sourceTimeZone));
Console.WriteLine(utc_time_start.ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ"));
```

The problem is that this piece of code gives **20191112T120000Z** as output when run on Dev system (based in IST timezone) whereas same code results in **20191112T110000Z** as output when run on server (based in EST). Is this behavior due to difference in timezone of the systems on which it is being run? What is could be a possible solution for this situation? A particular time from a particular timezone should result in same UTC time irrespective of the machine where the code executes.

Comment: First of all, in DateTime.Parse you can specify which time zone you can expect in this string. If you didn't specify this - it will use local machine time zone and convert accordingly

Comment: To work with time zone it is better to use DateTimeOffset because it has more methods to work with time zones

Comment: @MichaelKokorin I'm not sure it's accurate to say "you can specify a timezone when parsing" - you can specify an *offset*, but that is not the same thing as a *timezone*

Comment: Remember, by default, most servers are running in UTC.  IMO you should assume that servers run in UTC, and code against it.   Always specifying the timezone when parsing and displaying is a reasonable way around the problem.

Comment: @neil In my case, the server is in ET (Eastern Time) and I need to be able to convert time to UTC from any timezone. How can I achieve this? It would help if you can share some code.

Comment: @MichaelKokorin - your first comment is incorrect.  `DateTime.Parse` on the string shown here will use `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` because it does not contain any time zone information.  See the  remarks section of the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=netframework-4.8#System_DateTime_Parse_System_String_).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time zone that your server is running in does not impact this code.

The difference is due to [the end of DST for Brazil in 2019](https://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/brazil-scraps-dst.html).

Windows released [an update in July 2019](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Daylight-Saving-Time-Time-Zone/Time-zone-updates-for-Brazil-are-available/ba-p/751175) to cover this scenario.  Specifically, this change is addressed by [KB4507704](https://support.microsoft.com/help/4507704) and [Windows 10 Build 17763.652](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4505658).  Your dev environment has this update, the server does not.  You should ensure your server is receiving Windows Updates.  If it's missing this (5 months after release), it's probably missing more critical security updates as well.

Additionally, I *strongly* discourage matching time zone by display name for a few reasons:

- The display names are localized by the primary language of the operating system, so they will be different, for example, on a server set for English than on a server set for Portuguese.  (The globalization and localization settings in .NET are not used for this.)
- The display names are potentially volatile.  That is, if there is a reason to change the display name in a future update, the string will change from what you previously had used.

Instead, pass the `Id` of the time zone as an input to `TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById`, and skip the matching bit in the middle entirely.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your insight. This information is very helpful. I will make changes as you have suggested. Just one question though - when you say that I should pass `Id` instead of comparing display names; I am assuming that you are referring to **E. South America Standard Time** and similar values for other timezones.

Comment: Yes,  That is the value from `TimeZoneInfo.Id`, and corresponds to the key for the time zone in the Windows registry.  It is guaranteed to not change.  You should store that in your database.  Show the corresponding `DisplayName` to show to your end-user, but don't save it or pass it in APIs.

Answer (score 0):

You are not leaving your loop after you found a source time zone.

In your second part you search for a partial string of the time zone. Most probably this part finds a second time zone on your server. This can happen if the OS or .net versions differ.

Try:

```cs
string inputDateString = "2019-11-12T09:00:00.000"; //Taken as input from user
string inputTimeZoneString = "(UTC-03:00) Brasilia"; // Taken as input from user

var dtStartdatetime = DateTime.Parse(inputDateString);

string sourceTimeZone = string.Empty;
foreach (TimeZoneInfo a in TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones())
{
     if (a.DisplayName == inputTimeZoneString)
     {
          sourceTimeZone = a.Id;
         break;
     }
     string strTimeZone = a.DisplayName.Substring(a.DisplayName.IndexOf(')') + 1);
     string strTimeZone1 = inputTimeZoneString.Substring(inputTimeZoneString.IndexOf(')') + 1);
     if (strTimeZone.Trim() == strTimeZone1.Trim())
     {
          sourceTimeZone = a.Id;
         break;
     }
}

DateTime utc_time_start = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dtStartdatetime, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(sourceTimeZone));
Console.WriteLine(utc_time_start.ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ"));
```

Comment: I tried adding a break but to no avail. As for your second point regarding partial string search; I tried checking sourceTimeZone value and get **E. South America Standard Time** on both machines but the resultant time is still different.

Comment: Seems to be a configuration difference. I think you have to start comparing the wrong system with the right one. The base UTC offset of the found TimeZoneInfo is the same? Both machines have the same OS and OS version? Both have the same time settings?